# How to export data files with sequence file names?

Tags: list-manipulation, export

I want to export sequence text files. I can `Export` a single text file, designating the Directory, however I cannot make it to several files.

I thought if I have data called `input`, I can get 6 text files in the current directory, such as "C:\testfolder\new1.txt", "C:\testfolder\new2.txt", ..., "C:\testfolder\new6.txt".

However `{$Failed, $Failed, $Failed, $Failed, $Failed, $Failed}` is returned.

If someone knows how to do this, please tell me.

```
input = {{{6, 7, 9, 1, 5, 5, 7, 3, 7, 4}, {2, 7, 3, 2, 0, 10, 1, 0, 4,
  3}, {0, 0, 4, 10, 0, 8, 7, 2, 2, 5}, {6, 1, 5, 10, 3, 1, 3, 10, 
 5, 7}}, {{6, 10, 6, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 6}, {4, 2, 6, 5, 1, 8, 9, 
 7, 3, 9}, {4, 5, 8, 0, 9, 5, 4, 8, 9, 6}, {1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 7, 3, 
 4, 2, 3}}, {{4, 6, 9, 10, 3, 3, 0, 1, 7, 6}, {3, 2, 10, 8, 3, 2, 
 3, 6, 2, 2}, {10, 0, 3, 7, 1, 1, 3, 10, 5, 4}, {4, 7, 3, 2, 2, 4,
  9, 4, 3, 0}}, {{8, 9, 0, 10, 1, 7, 2, 10, 4, 0}, {9, 10, 4, 9, 
 4, 10, 0, 2, 5, 8}, {4, 6, 4, 10, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 5}, {8, 1, 1, 2,
  2, 1, 5, 7, 2, 8}}, {{0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 
 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 
 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0}}, {{13, 4, 3, 6, 8, 19, 7, 3, 4, 12}, {6, 9,
  1, 9, 13, 11, 3, 11, 8, 2}, {12, 9, 4, 18, 14, 3, 8, 9, 12, 
 1}, {8, 11, 4, 3, 15, 0, 11, 7, 18, 2}}};

st = StringJoin["C:\\testfolder\\new", ToString[#], ".txt"] & /@ 
stringform = ToString[TextString[#] // InputForm] & /@ st
Export[stringform[[#]], input[[#]], "Table"] & /@ Range[Length[st]]
```

Comment: The line `st = StringJoin["C:\\testfolder\\new", ToString[#], ".txt"] & /@` obviously makes no sense. Do you mis-copy the code sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
input = {{{6, 7, 9, 1, 5, 5, 7, 3, 7, 4}, {2, 7, 3, 2, 0, 10, 1, 0, 4,
      3}, {0, 0, 4, 10, 0, 8, 7, 2, 2, 5}, {6, 1, 5, 10, 3, 1, 3, 10, 
     5, 7}}, {{6, 10, 6, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 6}, {4, 2, 6, 5, 1, 8, 9, 
     7, 3, 9}, {4, 5, 8, 0, 9, 5, 4, 8, 9, 6}, {1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 7, 3, 
     4, 2, 3}}, {{4, 6, 9, 10, 3, 3, 0, 1, 7, 6}, {3, 2, 10, 8, 3, 2, 
     3, 6, 2, 2}, {10, 0, 3, 7, 1, 1, 3, 10, 5, 4}, {4, 7, 3, 2, 2, 4,
      9, 4, 3, 0}}, {{8, 9, 0, 10, 1, 7, 2, 10, 4, 0}, {9, 10, 4, 9, 
     4, 10, 0, 2, 5, 8}, {4, 6, 4, 10, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 5}, {8, 1, 1, 2,
      2, 1, 5, 7, 2, 8}}, {{0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 
     1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 
     1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0}}, {{13, 4, 3, 6, 8, 19, 7, 3, 4, 12}, {6, 9,
      1, 9, 13, 11, 3, 11, 8, 2}, {12, 9, 4, 18, 14, 3, 8, 9, 12, 
     1}, {8, 11, 4, 3, 15, 0, 11, 7, 18, 2}}};

Dimensions@input
```

> {6, 4, 10}

Create the file names:

```
st = StringJoin[{"C:/test/new", ToString[#], ".txt"}] & /@ Range[6]
```

> {"C:/test/new1.txt", "C:/test/new2.txt", "C:/test/new3.txt", 
> "C:/test/new4.txt", "C:/test/new5.txt", "C:/test/new6.txt"}

```
Export[st[[#]], input[[#]], "Table"] & /@ Range[Length[st]]
```

---

OR

**Using `MapIndexed`:**

```
MapIndexed[
 Export["C:/test/new" <> ToString[First@#2] <> ".txt", #1, 
   "Table"] &, input]
```

Comment: Please explore the `FileNameJoin` command as well.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Now I could successfully export them.